Excel de on,t need Filter function to replace null with 0
I am using the filter function but it replaces null cellules's values with 0 , this causes wrong sum and avereges for my sheet .
How to let null values using this filter function please?
Thanks

Why not just exclude nulls in your filter?

it's not clear what your filter is but if you are looking for numeric data and including zeros, or something along those lines, this would work if you included in column  that's filled with blanks, letters and numbers...
=LET(aRng,A:A,FILTER(aRng,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(aRng)),ISNUMBER(aRng))))

